# FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined index:"

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

We are running Wordpress on Nginx and receive these errors in our log:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: test in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elfsight-instagram-feed-cc/api/index.php on line 1173" while reading response header from upstream
```

The particular line in the plugin reads:

```
if ($response_http_code === '429' && $config['test']['recursive_client'] === 'true') {
     sleep(1);
     return client_request($type, $url_orig, $options);
}
```

Not quite sure what this error means. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Plugin author said will provide a fix for this bug